# IActivatableViewModel is activated before the View, so UnhandledInteractionException is thrown in VM activation

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, reactiveui

I have a ViewModel, that uses an Interaction for each item from a queue that exists independent from both View and ViewModel. Processing is started in `this.WhenActivated` block, and it relies on `Interaction`. Handler for `Interation` is set in `IViewFor<MyViewModel>.WhenActivated`.

Due to the order of activations, `UnhandledInteractionException` is thrown.

```
using System;
using System.Reactive;
using System.Reactive.Disposables;
using System.Windows;
using ReactiveUI;

namespace RxActivationRepro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                ViewModel.Interaction.RegisterHandler(ctx =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Interaction!");
                    ctx.SetOutput(Unit.Default);
                });
            });
        }

        object? IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value;
        }

        public MainViewModel? ViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject, IActivatableViewModel
    {
        public MainViewModel()
        {
            this.WhenActivated( d =>
            {
                Interaction.Handle(Unit.Default)
                    .Subscribe(_ => { MessageBox.Show("Nope!"); }, ex => { MessageBox.Show(ex.Message); })
                    .DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }

        public ViewModelActivator Activator { get; } = new();
        public Interaction<Unit, Unit> Interaction { get; } = new();
    }
}
```

I would expect the below code to work, but it does not. I worked around the issue my removing the interface from the VM to disable the View activating the VM, and handle the activation manually, no big deal.

But is there a way to change the order of activations or defer VM activation for later? Or am I approaching this wrong?

Found in RxUI 7.4.0 (don't ask :P), but the same behaviour is in 17.17 + dotnet 6, so I gues it is by design.

**More context:**

I'm trying to achieve a feature seen for example in Rider, that when you open new solution having already one instance, you get a dialog asking whether to open new instance, or replace contents of current one. I will have it open a special edit window for each new file, hence `Interaction` to decouple the edit window from the ViewModel that monitors the request queue. Item in queue before the activation can happen, if you open new file edit before loging in. I also don't want to spam windows, so I want to await the `Interaction.Handle` call to have just one item being edited at the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, thanks to the SO community and especially just the website for being my yellow rubber ducky :)

```
namespace RxActivationRepro
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, IViewFor<MainViewModel>
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            ViewModel = new MainViewModel();
            InitializeComponent();
            this.WhenActivated(d =>
            {
                ViewModel.Interaction.RegisterHandler(ctx =>
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Interaction!");
                    ctx.SetOutput(Unit.Default);
                });
                
                ViewModel.InteractUntilDisposed().Subscribe().DisposeWith(d);
            });
        }

        object? IViewFor.ViewModel
        {
            get => ViewModel;
            set => ViewModel = (MainViewModel)value;
        }

        public MainViewModel? ViewModel { get; set; }
    }

    public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
    {
        public IObservable<Unit> InteractUntilDisposed()
        {
            return Observable.StartAsync(async ct =>
            {
                while (!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    await Interaction.Handle(Unit.Default);
                    await Task.Delay(5000);
                }
            });
        }

        public Interaction<Unit, Unit> Interaction { get; } = new();
    }
}
```